# create landing page with special layout

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I've created an asp.net site and I want to create a landind page in which users can submit connection information. I stumbled a lot when browsing the internet upon landing pages with special layout as described in the attached image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQM2M.jpg)

I'm wondering how can I create such a page with asp.net\html\javascript ?
thanks for all the help

Comment: It's not obvious what you're asking but from your image I guess you're not talking about html layouts but you want to open new browser window with a certain look. Take a look at js window.open(). https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Comment: that's what I was looking for, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

> I'm wondering how can I create such a page with asp.net\html\javascript

Well you write asp.net program files which are executed when the browser makes a request for the site. Those files then deliver html and javascript to the browser which uses that content to display a web page. Got it?